# OSMNX: Add fixme tag to the list of attributes available to an edge

Tags: osmnx

I am working on an OpenStreetMap data quality project and one of the objectives is identifying and fixing ways without speed limits or other attributes.

It would be helpful if the attributes of edges in a graph would include the **fixme** tag.  Currently, a small number of attributes such as **maxspeed** are included, but adding the **fixme** tag would help greatly in organizing this effort.

Is this possible to do already in OSMNX?  Or should I submit an enhancement request?

Comment: Yes just configure the `useful_tags_way` setting in the settings module. See the docs: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#module-osmnx.settings

Comment: That worked, thank you.  I had to retrieve the setting as list and then add my desired tags to the list.